# Is there a language that begins range expressions with the higher/later datum?

Tags: syntax, semantics, list-of-languages, numbers

If someone were to say

> There were between twenty and ten people at the event.

or

> I will be there from the fifth to the second of July.

that person would sound strange indeed, because in English the convention is for a range to start with the lower/smaller/earlier datum.

Is there a language where constructions such as the above are acceptable or the norm?

Comment: There's some discussion of the general problem [here, and a reference](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/100267/15299).

Comment: Seems like a function of locale and not strictly language.